# What are the best ways to search in logs?

Tags: unix, search, logging, grep, tail

In any kind of service what are the best ways to search in the logs for the following cases :

1 - If the bug has already occurred.
2 - If the bug is reproduced and one wants to catch the exception/error occurred.

Some of the ways that i know but inefficient are :

`tail -f production.log => log flows and you have to check manually.`
`tail -n1000 production.log => log for last 1000 lines`
`tail -f production.log | grep '500 Internal Server Error' => shows the flow of log for only one particular line that says 500.`

**I want to print for the 100 lines above the log so to print backtrace also in both the cases(especially for second).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` , i.e.:

```
sed  '/500 Internal Server Error/!d' sederror.log|sed 10q
```

---

Explanation:

```
sed  '/500 Internal Server Error/!d'
```

Will print only lines matching `500 Internal Server Error`

```
sed 100q
```

Displays the first 100 lines (emulates `tail -n 100`)

Answer (score 7):

Hope I understand exactly what you want.

use grep with -B option ( -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context) to tell how many lines to print before the line of search:

For finding the error in all the log:

```
grep  -B 100 '500 Internal Server Error' production.log
```

For real time error:

```
 tail -f production.log | grep  -B 100 '500 Internal Server Error'
```

Comment: Hi , this works if i have to search the log file . What if i m reproducing the bug and at runtime i want to print 100 lines before the error? Does this works in that case as well?

Comment: Again, hope I got you well, Do you mean that?
 `tail -f  production.log  | grep  -B 100 '500 Internal Server Error'`
This will do the job.